# Cannot Authenticate to website, Scrapy Spider, Bad Request

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to write a webscraper to study different social media platforms and now I'm working on one for Gab. When I try to log in I get what I believe is a 400 HTTP code, bad request and I'm not sure why.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser


class FeedparserSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'feedparser'
    allowed_domains = ['gab.com']
    start_urls = ['https://gab.com/auth/sign_in/']

    def parse(self, response):

        # Everything we need to sign in 
        authenticity_token = response.xpath('//form[@class="simple_form new_user"]/input[@name="authenticity_token"]/@value').get()
        user_email = "my@eamiladdress.com"
        user_password = "MyPassword"

        open_in_browser(response)

        return FormRequest.from_response("https://gab.com/auth/sign_in", formdata={
            'authenticity_token': authenticity_token,
            'user[email]' : user_email,
            'user[password]': user_password,
        }, callback=self.parsefeed)

    def parsefeed(self, response):
        home_url = 'https://gab.com/home'
        yield scrapy.Request(url=home_url, callback=self.parse_feed)

    def parse_feed(self, response):
        open_in_browser(response)
```

[Current Predicament](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmUkL.png)

I suspect I'll need to change my formdata to include a user object with an email and a password property but I'm not sure.

I am VERY new to web scraping so dont have many troubleshooting strategies or insight yet. Any advice on what and how I should proceed would be very helpful and if this post could use any additional details please let me know and  will add it as quickly as possible.

Comment: try passing a headers dictionary to `FormRequest.from_response(...)`. You can get it by inspecting the network tab while manually logging in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass 'FormRequest.from_response' your response:

```
return FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={
            'authenticity_token': authenticity_token,
            'user[email]' : user_email,
            'user[password]': user_password},
             callback=self.parsefeed)
```

Then you'll get to a page with the following text:

```
To use the Gab Social web application, please enable JavaScript. Alternatively, try one of the <a href="https://apps.gab.com">native apps</a> for Gab Social for your platform.
```

You need to check how to website checks for javascript and see if you can bypass it.

Comment: Hey there, So I believe I've solved that problem by using a special docker container with a modified version of splash that eliminates content security policies.last night I wrote a lua script to sign in to the website, but it "just stopped working" any idea how I should proceed?

Comment: @DJK no, sorry.;